# Regex To Sort A String Containing Digits

Tags: javascript, regex, string, sorting

I have a string which contains digits. I need to sort this string using regular expression.

```
var myString = "85762034834126745305743";
```

I'm looking for a complete solution which only use regular expression. Just need your thought on this whether it can be achieved or not.

Comment: Is there a reason you would like to use regex for this task?

Comment: Regular expressions cannot 'sort' a string.

Comment: @p.s.w.g So this can only be achieved with the help of a loop ?

Comment: Regular Expressions only match patterns they do not influence those matches.

Comment: Regular expressions allow you to check if a string matches a pattern, and possibly extract subsets of the string. Sorting means putting a list of items in a certain order. The two are unrelated concepts.

Comment: Sorting is actually a really rich and complex topic. One way is to loop over the elements but you can also use sorted data types to rebuild your array of ints into a sorted set.

Comment: `Just need your thought on this whether it can be achieved or not`—it can't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regular expressions are not suited for this kind of task. Plain old JavaScript is a lot simpler and easier:

```
"85762034834126745305743".split("").sort().join("") // "00122333344445556677788"
```